# Setup of tables to enable me to related records to eachother?

Tags: sql, database, layout

I am trying to figure out how I can relate records form 1 table to each other

I have a table with Individual cases (e.g disciplinary, grievance etc)

However, multiples of these cases could relate to each other.
e.g a group of people get into a fight, all the people involved would get an individual case, then all the cases would need to be related/linked.

Im struggling to figure out how would be best to store this data, whether it be in the same table or a new table.

[image: Example data]

This is the backend to a Winform. So now I need to be able to link records, in the example data the user would select that caseID 1- 4 are linked.

So the question is how do i store the data that these cases are related. Because other case might be linked at a later date.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would help.

Comment: I have attached some sample data, but this post is asking how i can store the LINK data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need some sort of "master case" or "incident".

I think I would say that an "incident" comprises one or more "cases" and keep both an `incidents` and `cases` tables.  In fact `cases` might be a bad name.  Instead, it might be more like `IncidentPerson`.

An alternative approach would be to have a "master case" id on each `case`.  This could be `NULL` or the same case.  I'm not as fond of this approach because it will likely lead to confusion down the road.  One analyst will count cases per month using "cases" and another using "master cases" and you'll spend a lot of time trying to figure out why the numbers are different.

Comment: Yes this should work! Thank you for taking your time to respond